# Create New MySQL table with structure of existing table

Tags: mysql

How to create a new MySQL Table B with the same columns, keys, and indexes as Table A but not the data. 
I want a new empty table with basically all the same structure as an existing table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1487/copy-an-existing-mysql-table-to-a-new-table/

```
CREATE TABLE Table_B LIKE Table_A;
```

which did what I wanted.

Here is the [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-like.html)